# Importing .pfx certificate and signing binaries

Tags: certificate, sign, pfx, signtool

In our build procedure, we are using .pfx file to sign our generated binaries, while referencing the time stamp server.

**Is it possible to import/install this into the build machine (Windows Server 8.x) and sign our binaries, instead of manually referring .pfx file to SignTool.exe?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, here is the command which signs TestLibrary.dll with "Test Certificate" from "CodeSigningCertificates" machine store:

```
signtool sign /v /sm /s CodeSigningCertificates /n "Test Certificate" c:\TestFiles\TestLibrary.dll
```

Here are some links with details on signtool and command line parameters:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/11/13/steps-to-sign-a-file-using-signtool-exe.aspx

Just be aware that user who runs the build must have permission to access certain certificate location and store and have access to private key.